# Unmarshalling empty tag into new instances of collections

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshal something like below into their JAXB equivalents, and the fields are as expected being populated with nulls

XML

```
<University>
   <StudentFirstNames/>
</University>
```

JAXB POJO

```
public class University {
  List<StudentFirstNames> studentFirstNames = null;

  public void getStudentFirstNames() {
    return studentFirstNames 
   }

  public void setStudentFirstNames() {
   this.studentFirsNames = studentFirstNames;
  }
}
```

After unmarshalling I am returned back null when I lookup the member in the JAXB object

```
 university.getStudentFirstNames() --> null
```

In this specific situation I am trying to resolve, I need to replace empty tags with new instance of that particular type. For example in the above, I am expecting back a new ArrayList () instead of null. I know this sounds counter intuitive but that is what I have to do for satisying code downstream.

Is there a global fix to resolve such instances. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if u try to add the annotation: @XmlElementWrapper to your List it should be represented as empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize your field as follows to get the desired behaviour:

```
List<StudentFirstNames> studentFirstNames = new ArrayList<StudentFirstNames>;
```

To be able to differentiate between a null and empty collection you will need to use an `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html

Comment: The initialization fixed it but still am confused as to how it worked! While unmarshalling though, wouldn't the setter for studentFirstNames reset it to a null since it read an empty tag?